# How can i return mobile version of site on WebView?

Tags: android, webview

I need to return mobile web site on the web view after user click on the desktop version of site. I packaged my site inside a web view, and I don’t want it to fire when the button is clicked on the full version of the site. So that in any case it returns the mobile version

```
`@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private void webClient_old() {
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String new_url) {
                if(new_url.contains("https://somesite.top/")){
                   
                    view.loadUrl(new_url);
                }

              
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {

                my_url = view.getUrl();
               
                if (!my_links.contains(view.getUrl())) {
                    my_links.add(view.getUrl());

                }

            }
        });
}`
```

Thank you for any help